# Find files created 1 hour ago

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, aix

I want to list files with long description on AIX that was created from 1 hour ago. I am trying 
find . -cmin -60 but it only shows the file names. Was trying also find . -cmin -60 -exec ls -l {} \; but it was displaying the whole files in the directory.

Thank you

Comment: As you may have known, AIX filesystem doesn't keep the file creation time
as other Unix based system. The `-cmin n` option in `find` specifies
the file's *status was last changed* n minutes ago.
If you mention about the file modification time, try `-mmin` option instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
find . -cmin +60 -exec ls -al {} \;
```

It will list all the files in current directory created more than 60 minutes agp.

The '+' in the '+60' means more than 60 minutes ago while a '-' in the '-60' means less than 60 minutes ago.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But what I need are the files from 1 hour ago. Example current time is at 10:24AM, files from 9:24 to current are the files that I needed. Thanks anyway. That's why I used -60.

Comment: So what you need will be like this: find . -cmin -60 -exec ls -al {} \;

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

```
find . -cmin -60 -exec ls -ld {} \;
find . -cmin -60 -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
find . -cmin -60 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
find . -cmin -60 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l
```

The last two are better, but require GNU-findutils.

Edit: As noted by others, `-cmin -60` means recently modified files, `-cmin +60` means the not-recently modified files.

Answer (score 0):

When your `find` lacks a `cmin` option, you can `touch` a file with a timestamp 1 hour ago and use the `find` with `-newer`.